# parsec how to recursively parse simple expression?

Tags: haskell, parsec, megaparsec

I have a strings like that: `***`, `**(*)*`, `****(**(**)*)**`

And I want to parse it in the data structure like that:

`data Tree = Node [S] Tree Tree | Empty` where `S` is `*`
(`*` doesn't mean any char it is just star symbol)

I tried to build parser (I use `megaparsec` but it is very similar to habitual `parsec`):

```
data Tree = Node [Char] Tree Tree | Empty deriving (Show)

chain :: Parser Tree 
chain = do
    line <- many $ char '*'
    branch <- between (char '(') (char ')') chain
    cont <- (eof >> return Empty) <|> chain
    return $ Node line branch cont

test = parseTest chain "****(*(*)***)*(*)**"
```

But It doesn't work. I tried many ways but can't struggle with it.

Comment: I suspect you need a `try` before the recursive call.

Comment: I do it, but it's not working:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with a simpler test case:

```
> parseTest chain "*"
parse error at (line 1, column 2):
unexpected end of input
expecting "*" or "("
```

Note that there's a parse error after reading the first star.  The input ended, but the parser expected to read either another star or an open parenthesis.

Looking at your parser, it's clear that:

```
line <- many $ char '*'
```

succeeds, by reading the first string of stars, but the next line:

```
branch <- between (char '(') (char ')') chain
```

requires an open parenthesis in the input, and this is not made optional in any way.

We could fix this by writing:

```
branch <- option Empty $ between (char '(') (char ')') chain
```

Now, the parser works okay on `"***"`, but it hangs on `"**(*)*"`.  The problem is the line:

```
cont <- (eof >> return Empty) <|> chain
```

This tries to decide when to stop parsing based on detecting the end of input, but this only works at the top level `chain` call where the end of the current tree corresponds to the end of the input -- in a recursive call, the tree can end before the input does, so this won't work.

Specifically, in the test case `"**(*)*"`, when parsing the tree inside the parentheses, namely `*`, we get `line` set to `*`, `branch` set to `Empty`, and then the `cont` line sees that we aren't at the end of the input (since the rest of the input `")*"` is still to be read) and recursively calls `chain`.  In this recursive call, `line` gets set to the empty string, `branch` gets set to `Empty`, and the `cont` line again causes a recursive call to `chain`, and we have an infinite loop.

Instead, let's write a parser `tree` that parses the `line` of a tree:

```
tree = do
  line <- many $ char '*'
```

and now *optionally* a `tree` in parenthesis (for the left hand side):

```
  mleft  <- optionMaybe $ between (char '(') (char ')') tree
```

If there is no left-hand side, then there can't be a right hand side either (convince yourself that this is true! -- try to write a tree that has no left hand side in parenthesis but still has a non-empty right hand side, and you'll see it can't be done), so we're finished:

```
  case mleft of
    Nothing -> return $ Node line Empty Empty
```

If there is a left-hand side, then read the right hand side tree (which might be empty, but that's okay) and return the node:

```
    Just left -> do
      right <- tree
      return $ Node line left right
```

The whole parser looks like:

```
tree :: Parser Tree
tree = do
  line <- many $ char '*'
  mleft  <- optionMaybe $ between (char '(') (char ')') tree
  case mleft of
    Nothing -> return $ Node line Empty Empty
    Just left -> do
      right <- tree
      return $ Node line left right
```

and hopefully does what you expect:

```
> parseTest tree "*"
Node "*" Empty Empty
> parseTest tree "***"
Node "***" Empty Empty
> parseTest tree "**(*)*"
Node "**" (Node "*" Empty Empty) (Node "*" Empty Empty)
> parseTest tree "****(**(**)*)**"
Node "****" (Node "**" (Node "**" Empty Empty)
    (Node "*" Empty Empty)) (Node "**" Empty Empty)
```

This parser just ignores trailing input:

```
> parseTest tree "*hello*"
Node "*" Empty Empty
```

but you can write a wrapper to require the end of the outermost tree correspond to the end of input:

```
treeOnly :: Parser Tree
treeOnly = tree <* eof
```